# TDD RSpec Capybara Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am trying to familiarize with Capybara and other TDD and I am failing at failing. My first example here(scenario "unsuccessfully post a message no user" do) should be a fail since I didn't input the user  but it is somehow getting inputted anyways as instead of receiving the expected "User must exist" it says "Welcome John". Is my 'before(:each)' still hitting it even though it comes after or do I have some other problem?

/spec/features/mess_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'
feature "post message" do
    scenario "unsuccessfully post a message no user" do
        visit messages_path
        fill_in "message[content]", with: "This is the content of my message."
        click_button "Post a Message"
        expect(page).to have_content "User must exist"      
    end
    before(:each) do 
        visit new_user_path
        fill_in "user[name]", with: "John"
        click_button "Sign In"
        visit messages_path
    end
    scenario "successfully post a message" do
        fill_in "message[content]", with: "This is the content of my message."
        click_button "Post a Message"
        expect(page).to have_content "This is the content of my message"
        expect(current_path).to eq(messages_path)
    end
    scenario "unsuccessfully post a message no content" do
        fill_in "message[content]", with: ""
        click_button "Post a Message"
        expect(page).to have_content "Content is too short"     
    end
    scenario "messages page should have a log out button" do
        click_button "logout"
        expect(current_path).to eq(new_user_path)
    end
end
```

I was having a similiar problem with my spec/models/message_spec.rb as my 2nd test

```
it "should not save if no user" do 
     expect(build(:message)).to be_invalid
   end
```

was failing to fail also although I just cheated on that by skipping the factory bot so here is my current working file

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Message, type: :model do
    it "should save" do      
      expect(build(:message, user: build(:user))).to be_valid
    end
    it "should not save if no user" do 
      message = Message.new(
        content: 'This is a message'               
      )
      expect(message).to be_invalid
    end     
    it "should not save content is too short" do 
      message = Message.new(
        content: 'This',
        user_id: '1'       
      )
      expect(message).to be_invalid
    end         
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have correctly guessed at your issue - `scenario` just defines the test - it's not defining the order of tests, and best practice is to actually run your tests in a random order to ensure you don't have any coupling between individual tests.  This means any `before(:each)` defined within the same scope, or higher, will be run before every `scenario` specified in that scope.

To solve this you can use any of RSpecs other keyworsd that will form a new scope, such as

```
feature "post message" do
    context "with no user" do
      scenario "unsuccessfully post a message no user" do
          visit messages_path
          fill_in "message[content]", with: "This is the content of my message."
          click_button "Post a Message"
          expect(page).to have_content "User must exist"      
      end
    end

    context "with a user" do
      before(:each) do 
        visit new_user_path
        fill_in "user[name]", with: "John"
        click_button "Sign In"
        visit messages_path
      end

      scenario "successfully post a message" do
        fill_in "message[content]", with: "This is the content of my message."
        click_button "Post a Message"
        expect(page).to have_content "This is the content of my message"
        expect(page).to have_current_path(messages_path)
      end
      scenario "unsuccessfully post a message no content" do
        fill_in "message[content]", with: ""
        click_button "Post a Message"
        expect(page).to have_content "Content is too short"     
      end
      scenario "messages page should have a log out button" do
        click_button "logout"
        expect(page).to have_current_path(new_user_path)
      end
    end
end
```

Additionally you shouldn't be using RSpecs built-in matchers (`eq`, etc) with Capybara - instead use the matchers provided by Capybara, in this case `have_current_path` as I've shown above. These have retrying behavior and will lead to much more stable tests when you're dealing with pages including asynchronous behavior.